# Registry key for WCF services in windows 10

Tags: wcf

I had to check if **HTTP Activation** in **.NET Framework 4.5 Advanced Services** > **WCF Services** is enable or not in windows 10.

Where i can find the registry key for it?

Comment: why you need registry key for enabling wcf services module?

Comment: I dont want to enable via registry key. I just want to know where the registry key of the same will be register in the registry table after enabling.